# How to implement polymorphic current_user nicely

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In my app I have two types of users (`User` and `Shop` now, will add `Admin` soon) which are authenticated through the same auth strategy, and thus are stored in the same `current_profile` variable. So, it could be an instance of several models, that's why I'm fetching it with following method:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_action :fetch_current_user

  private

  def fetch_current_user
    if session[:current_profile_type].blank?
      @current_profile = nil
      return
    end

    case session[:current_profile_type]
    when 'Shop'
      model = Shop
    when 'User'
      model = User
    end

    @current_profile = model.find_by(id: session[:current_profile_id])
  end
end
```

But I'm unhappy with this solution, it looks like too noisy for me. Maybe there is a better/simpler approach?

P.S. I don't like to use `constantize` here: while be more readable it'll slow down every app's request.

Comment: Not to nit-pick, but this will clean up your code. `klass = session[:current_profile_type].constantize`, and you can `klass.find()` without your case statement.

Comment: Then `constantize` will be executed on every request and I'm sure that searching through constants is much slower than simple `case`. But thanks for your suggestion)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one possibility

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  PROFILE_TYPES = {
    'Shop': Shop,
    'User': User
  }

  before_action :fetch_current_user

  private

  def fetch_current_user
    profile_type = PROFILE_TYPES[session[:current_profile_type]]
    @current_profile = profile_type && profile_type.find_by(id: session[:current_profile_id])
  end
end
```

Or how about caching the results of `constantize`? That way you do not need to manually maintain a Hash map like in the example above.

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_action :fetch_current_user

  private

  def fetch_current_user
    profile_type = (self.class.cached_profile_types[session[:current_profile_type]] ||= session[:current_profile_type].constantize)  # Constantizes each type only once after each application boot.
    @current_profile = profile_type && profile_type.find_by(id: session[:current_profile_id])
  end

  def self.cached_profile_types
    @@cached_profile_types ||= {}  # Cache across all subclasses of ApplicationController
  end
end
```

Comment: Thank you, looks much cleaner! I wonder why I haven't come to the same solution.